# How get to know what font family does anchor element use

Tags: html, css, fonts

Firefox.
Firebug.
Simple task.
How get to know what font family does anchor element use?
I opened the element in Firebug. And what I see. 
[image]

Why font info is crossed? How determine what font was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "computed" tab instead. If that doesn't say what font is chosen - then it's probably some browser default and you're out of luck.